# How to initialize a list view where some items may be striked out?

Tags: android, listview, strikethrough

A have a list of `Strings`, lets say `{ "1", "2", "3" }`

When using `ArrayAdapters` I know how to add these strings to a `ListView`. I also know how to strike out some items on click using `OnItemClick`.

What I don't understand is how to strike out items when the list is being populated. Basically when the `ListView` loads, some items should be striked out and some not.

I've played around with `getAdapter` and `notifyDataSetChanged` to no avail.

How would I go about doing this? The information on the internet is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Strings.  You use an array of objects

```
public static class Item {
    String value;
    boolean isStruckOut;
}
```

And strikethrough or not based on the boolean at each index.  This will also require you to use a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"when the list is being populated"*?

I would use a function like this, whenever I add a new item to the list:

```
public void addItemToList(String item, boolean shouldStrike) {
    if (shouldStrike) {
        item = "<strike>" + item + "</strike>";
    }
    items.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```